# Swapping the first and last element in the array using assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, swap

```
segment .data
array: db 68,222,29,68,33,234,179,103,37,85
fmt: db ",%d",0

segment .text
        extern  printf
        global  asm_main
asm_main:
        enter   0,0               ; setup routine
        pusha
        
        push dword 10
        push dword array
        call print_array
        add  esp,8
        push dword 10
        push dword array

swap_byte_first_last:
        mov eax,[array]
        mov edx,[array+9]
        mov [array+9],eax
        mov [array],edx
        call print_array

; don't delete anything following this comment
        popa
        mov     eax, 0            ; return back to C
        leave                     
        ret

segment .data
ListFormat    db   ",%u", 0

segment .text
        global  print_array
print_array:
        enter   0,0
        push    esi
        push    ebx

        xor     esi, esi                  
        mov     ecx, [ebp+12]            
        mov     ebx, [ebp+8]              
        xor     edx,edx
        mov     dl,[ebx + esi]
        mov     eax,edx                       
        call    print_int
        dec     ecx
        inc     esi
print_loop:
        xor     edx,edx
        mov     dl,[ebx + esi]
        push    ecx                       
        push    edx                       
        push    dword ListFormat
        call    printf
        add     esp, 8                   
        inc     esi
        pop     ecx
        loop    print_loop
        call    print_nl

        pop     ebx
        pop     esi
        leave
        ret

%define A_ADDR [ebp+12]
%define B_ADDR [ebp+8]
%define A_VAL [eax]
%define B_VAL [ebx]

segment .text
        global  swap_byte
swap_byte:
        enter   0,0
        pusha
        mov     eax, A_ADDR             
        mov     ebx, B_ADDR             
        mov     dl,A_VAL               
        mov     cl,B_VAL               
        mov     [eax],cl
        mov     [ebx],dl
        popa

        leave
        ret
```

This prints 85,44,37,100,33,234,179,103,37,68. The result should be 85,222,29,68,33,234,179,103,37,68.
I was able to swap first element (68) with the last element (85), but numbers 222,29,and 68 have changed to 44,37,and 100. What changes do I need to make with the codes in swap_byte_first_last? Other parts of the code were given.

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed eax and edx with al and dl and it worked.

Comment: Then how would I make this array rotate to the right 1 time?

Comment: Save the last element, then `memmove(array+1, array, 9)`, then store that saved element.  The memmove can use dword copies for efficiency.